# Find ISBN of a list with many books

Tags: csv, isbn

I have a list of books titles, and want to attach the ISBN to each one of those automatically. Each book is located in a .csv file. Any ideas if that is possible online?

Thanks!

Comment: Different editions of a book have different ISBNs, so it is unlikely to find any accurate method to do this.

Comment: Any ISBN version will do!

Comment: @OliverAmundsen did you do an app for this? I have need of a script/app for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the python package [isbntools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbntools) and you can use the command `isbn_from_words "author title"` to get the most probable ISBN.